# Uncaught TypeError with an id name

Tags: javascript

#### The error *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null* is alerted for the following JavaScript, even though the HTML has the same id name.

### Script

```
var ctdwnSec = document.getElementById("ctdwnTimeDispSec").value;
```

### HTML

```
<input type="text" value="0" id="ctdwnTimeDispSec"/>
```

Comment: Is this script executed in your document head?

Comment: Yes it's in the head.

Comment: That's your problem then; either put it somewhere after your html, or put it in an on-load handler.  It isn't working because the document has yet to finish loading by the time it is executed.